# How to use continue as a parameter for a method

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

in the json file i receive as respone it contains a key "continue" and to create the model object for the response i have to use "continue" as a parameter in the method.

**Activity**

```
public object Model {
data class ResultOfContinue(val continue: Continue)
}
```

**json**

```
"batchcomplete": "",
"continue": {
    "sroffset": 10,
    "continue": "-||"
},
```

Comment: You cannot use keywords for variable/class names. It would be better to refactor it to something similar like `ContinueJson` or `ContinueObj`.

Comment: Most json parsing frameworks have a way to specify the serialized name differently from the program/field name. For example, Gson will let you annotate your field with `@SerializedName("continue")` and then choose a different (non-keyword) name for the actual field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wanna use `keyword` as a parameter. You can use like this :

```
data class ResultOfContinue(val `continue`: Continue) {
}
```